# UIbutton of scrollview not interacting

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

My problem is that my Button and other all controls are not working when i have adding scrollview programmatically to my subView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 if(self.appDelegate.screenWidth < 568){
        self.scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.appDelegate.screenWidth, 568)
        scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
        scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        // mainView consists all other controls like UIButton and other
        scrollView.addSubview(mainView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }
}


  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if(self.appDelegate.screenWidth < 568){
        scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        mainView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Any suggestions for solving this query???

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see the call to super.viewDidLoad()

Comment: Please see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

I truly believe its the issue with your view hierarchy. You are adding your scroll view on top of all other UI controls `UIButton` etc. All the UI controls should be sub-view of scroll view for scroll and controls to function well.

Comment: No.. My mainView is subView of scroll view and mainView consists all controls

Comment: I have added userInteractionEnable to NO for scroll view, now scrolling also not working .. please suggest me any other solution for scroll view

Comment: Please show code of your buttons and main view and place where these are being added to scroll view.

Comment: I have added other controls and mainView from xCode

Comment: canCancelContentTouches change to false instead of true then interaction working and scrolling not working

Comment: Can you please check your storyboard view hierarchy and ensure that there is no transparent view covering your controls and if there is one and is needed by you then you need to set `userInteractionsEnabled` property to `NO` so touches could reach them.

Comment: I thought you always set `canCancelContentTouches` to `false`.